# Find a coordinate in a multidimensional array using string search

Tags: javascript, arrays, stringify

Try to give an alternative in this question WITHOUT LOOPING! Just using indexOf and some integer math

[Get coordinates of an element in multidimentional array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144993/get-coordinates-of-an-element-in-multidimentional-array-in-javascript)

The code below seemed promising but fails.

Anyone with better math skills feel like fixing it?

```js
var letterVariations = [ 
        [' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
        ['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e',';'],
        ['Â','â','F','f','G','g','H','h','Ê','ê',':'],
        ['À','à','I','i','J','j','K','k','È','è','.'],
        ['L','l','Î','î','M','m','N','n','É','é','?'],
        ['O','o','Ï','ï','P','p','Q','q','R','r','!'],
        ['Ô','ô','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','“'],
        ['W','w','X','x','Y','y','Ù','ù','Z','z','”'],
        ['@','&','#','[','(','/',')',']','+','=','-'],
    ];

var string = JSON.stringify(letterVariations);
var pos = string.indexOf("u")
console.log(Math.floor((pos/10)%9),pos%10)

// fails, how to fix?
pos = string.indexOf("M")
console.log(Math.floor((pos/10)%9),pos%10)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with "`% 8`"?

Comment: JSON.strinigfy gives you string like `[[" ","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],["A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e",";"]...`, you can't search here, it's better to use `letterVariations.toString()`

Comment: Divide with width and height to get the pos

Comment: Well, that's an 11 x 9 grid, not 10 x 8.

Comment: For the `x` position, I think you can try to proportionate the value to the length of the string. Example: `u` has index 307, using: `Math.floor((pos*11)/string.length)` you can get the `x` position, which is 8 in that case. It's 11 because it's an 11x9 grid. I'm not sure how you can get the Y value though.

Comment: @AlexOwl has the right problem. The index of `M` in the string is 203, this includes all the quotes and the `[, ]` characters. It's not the 203rd index as the array is indexed. Consider the array `let r = ['m']` if you stringily that and look for the index of `m` you will get 2 not zero.

Comment: I don't know, something like that should work: https://jsfiddle.net/gwfr5m21/ I'm not a math dude, but using floor for X and ceil for Y seems to work. A thousand unit tests would help here. Perhaps some tweaks are necessary, but it may be a good starting point

Comment: I was also playing  with ceil and floor

Comment: @briosheje you can't find right index in `JSON.stringify` string

Comment: @mplungjan check out my answer!

Comment: @AlexOwl mind explaining why? JSON.stringify does not add things arbitrarely and, since the length of each item of the array is always the same, you should be able to get informations back. Besides, I think the original question is to **fix** the code he provided by keeping the logic of what is currently written.

Comment: @briosheje JSON.stringify adds braces and quotes like `[["1","2"], ["3","4"]]` - you can't get right position using `.infdexOf()` on such string

Comment: @AlexOwl That's always proportional, though. I don't think it's **impossible** to actually get the right index, I think the question is rather **how much complex** it is.

Comment: @briosheje to get plain string of symbols he can use `.toString().replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: @AlexOwl assuming all entries are only one character.

Comment: It boggles my mind why someone would care so much about this question to vote it down

Comment: And again.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function findPos(array, symbol) {
  const string = array.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  const pos = string.indexOf(symbol)

  const d = (array[0] || []).length

  const x = pos % d;
  const y = Math.floor(pos / d)

  return { x, y }
}

const array = [
  [' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
  ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', ';'],
  ['Â', 'â', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'Ê', 'ê', ':'],
  ['À', 'à', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'È', 'è', '.'],
  ['L', 'l', 'Î', 'î', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'É', 'é', '?'],
  ['O', 'o', 'Ï', 'ï', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', '!'],
  ['Ô', 'ô', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', '“'],
  ['W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Ù', 'ù', 'Z', 'z', '”'],
  ['@', '&', '#', '[', '(', '/', ')', ']', '+', '=', '-'],
];


console.log(findPos(array,' ')) //=> [0, 0]
console.log(findPos(array,'M')) //=> [4, 4]
console.log(findPos(array,'u')) //=> [6, 7]
console.log(findPos(array,'-')) //=> [8, 10]
```

Comment: What happens if one of the entries is more than one character?

Comment: @MarkMeyer it brokes) You need to use normal solution like above to handle such cases

Comment: Oh, ok, that's interesting. Mind explaining how X and Y are calculated? That answers the question anyway. Of course, elements with more than one character would break the algorithm but still, I think this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could join the strings and use the length of the inner array as value for divisioin or for the remainder operator. This works only for strings with a single character.

```js
var letterVariations = [
        [' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
        ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', ';'],
        ['Â', 'â', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'Ê', 'ê', ':'],
        ['À', 'à', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'È', 'è', '.'],
        ['L', 'l', 'Î', 'î', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'É', 'é', '?'],
        ['O', 'o', 'Ï', 'ï', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', '!'],
        ['Ô', 'ô', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', '“'],
        ['W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Ù', 'ù', 'Z', 'z', '”'],
        ['@', '&', '#', '[', '(', '/', ')', ']', '+', '=', '-']
    ],
    string = letterVariations.map(a => a.join('')).join(''),
    pos = string.indexOf("u");

console.log(Math.floor(pos / 11), pos % 11);

pos = string.indexOf("M")
console.log(Math.floor(pos / 11), pos % 11);
```

Comment: Is your map not a variation on stringify?

Comment: Why is there an overhead compared to map?

Comment: the stringified versiopn has quotes, commas and brackets, which generates an overhead of characters for getting the position and calculate the indices.

Comment: There are also some (likely unimportant, but real) performance advantages: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4740

Answer (score 1):

This produces the correct result. There is no need to stringify, you can flatten the arrays and use `indexOf` to get the position:

```js
var letterVariations = [
  [' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
  ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', ';'],
  ['Â', 'â', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'Ê', 'ê', ':'],
  ['À', 'à', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'È', 'è', '.'],
  ['L', 'l', 'Î', 'î', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'É', 'é', '?'],
  ['O', 'o', 'Ï', 'ï', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', '!'],
  ['Ô', 'ô', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', '“'],
  ['W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Ù', 'ù', 'Z', 'z', '”'],
  ['@', '&', '#', '[', '(', '/', ')', ']', '+', '=', '-'],
];

var flattened = letterVariations.flat()

var findLetter = function(letter) {
  var pos = flattened.indexOf(letter),
    x = Math.floor((pos / 10) % 8),
    y = (pos - (pos % 11)) / 11;
  return {
    letter: letter,
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}
console.log(findLetter(' ')) //=> [0, 0]
console.log(findLetter('M')) //=> [4, 4]
console.log(findLetter('u')) //=> [6, 7]
console.log(findLetter('-')) //=> [8, 10]
```

Comment: It fails on the last char

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version of that:

```js
var letterVariations = [ 
  [' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
  ['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e',';'],
  ['Â','â','F','f','G','g','H','h','Ê','ê',':'],
  ['À','à','I','i','J','j','K','k','È','è','.'],
  ['L','l','Î','î','M','m','N','n','É','é','?'],
  ['O','o','Ï','ï','P','p','Q','q','R','r','!'],
  ['Ô','ô','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','“'],
  ['W','w','X','x','Y','y','Ù','ù','Z','z','”'],
  ['@','&','#','[','(','/',')',']','+','=','-'],
];

const findLetterIn = letterVariations => {
  const width = letterVariations[0].length * 4 + 2;
  const alpha = JSON.stringify(letterVariations)

  return (char, pos = alpha.indexOf(char)) => pos > -1 
    ? [Math.floor((pos - 1) / width), (((pos - 1) % width) - 2)/4]
    : [-1, -1]
}

const findLetter = findLetterIn (letterVariations)

console.log(findLetter(' ')) //=> [0, 0]
console.log(findLetter('M')) //=> [4, 4]
console.log(findLetter('u')) //=> [6, 7]
console.log(findLetter('-')) //=> [8, 10]
```

Here `width` has to do with row width.

The `4`s have to do with `u ~> "u",`  The `+ 2` has to do with adding `[` and `]` to the beginning and end (as well as an additional `,` after the `]`, but removing one before it.) The `- 1` has to do with ignoring the initial `[` and the `- 2` has to do with removing the leading `,"` or, for the first one, the leading `["`.

You can switch to 1-based indices by adding 1 to both element of the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @GluePear answer

You can even use multi-chars in this solution

```js
function findPos(array, symbol) {
  const string = array.flat();
  const pos = string.indexOf(symbol)
  
  const d = (array[0] || []).length
  
  const x = pos % d;
  const y = Math.floor(pos / d)

  return { x, y }
}

const array = [ 
  [' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
  ['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e',';'],
  ['Â','â','F','f','G','g','H','h','Ê','ê',':'],
  ['À','à','I','i','J','j','K','k','È','è','.'],
  ['L','l','Î','î','M','m','N','n','É','é','?'],
  ['O','o','Ï','ï','P','p','Q','q','R','r','!'],
  ['Ô','ô','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','“'],
  ['W','w','X','x','Y','y','Ù','ù','Z','z','”'],
  ['@','&','#','[','(','/',')',']','+','=','-'],
 ];
  
  
console.log(findPos(array, '-'))
```